# How to install SMPP Protocol Support plugin in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter-plugins

unable to download SMPP plugin in JMeter website

SMPP protocol how it works

detailed information about how to download and installation in JMeter.

JMeter doesn't have built-in support for SMPP. We  need to install a third-party plugin called "SMPP Protocol Support" to enable SMPP functionality in JMeter & need to write customized  code as per the requirement then only we can able to send request via Jmeter tool

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any "SMPP plugin" in [JMeter Plugins Repository](https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/) and I doubt such a plugin exists.

So reach out to the person who provided this "detailed information about how to download and installation in JMeter" and ask him where and how you can get the plugin.

My expectation is that you will need to [create your own JMeter plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) using i.e. [jSMPP](https://jsmpp.org/) or [cloudhopper-smpp](https://github.com/fizzed/cloudhopper-smpp) SMPP Java client libraries